# Java and ALSA problems

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, java

I'm trying to use a Java-based application that requires sound in Ubuntu 10.04 using sun-java from partner repos . However, the sound is way too fast. It seems like a chipmunk got into my speakers. :)

Is this happening to anyone else? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

As "nhnb" says: it seems like this bug is fixed in OpenJDK.  OpenJDK is based on the open source parts from Sun Java, with the parts that are not open source replaced by alternative code, and which apparently also fixes some bugs...

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problems using pulse audio and Java applications, except for me I get no sound for my entire system once JVM starts... but if I have an application running before JVM starts, it's sound still works.

I run my java programs with aoss javaws /program/to/run

That fixes my sound, but makes the java programs crash a lot... so it's a trade off. In my opinion, Java's "cross platform" talk doesn't include Linux.

Comment: I can confirm this issue in Sun Java on Ubuntu 10.04. It does not exist in OpenJDK.

Comment: @nhnb: One more reason why open source > closed source, and people should just use OpenJDK instead of Sun Java...   ;-)